# Let $Y\sim\operatorname{Bin}(10,p)$ and X be the number of successes among the ﬁrst 3 trials.Compute$E[Y|X=x]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let Y be the number of successes in 10 independent Bernoulli trials with probability p of success and X be the number of successes among the ﬁrst 3 trials.Compute$E[Y|X=x]$

So$X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(3,p) \text{ while } Y\sim \operatorname{Bin}(10,p)$

$\displaystyle E[Y|X=x]\Rightarrow \sum_{y}^{} y \cdot P(Y=y|X=x)=\sum_{y}^{}y \cdot \frac{P(Y=y\cap X=x)}{{P(X=x)}}$

$\displaystyle =\sum_{y=x}^{10}y \cdot\frac{ P(\text{No. of successes in 7 remaining trials}=y-x)}{P(X=x)}$

$\displaystyle=\sum_{y=x}^{10}y \cdot\frac{ {7\choose y-x }{p^{y-x}(1-p)^{7-(y-x)}}}{{3\choose x}{p^x(1-p)^{3-x}}}\Rightarrow  \sum_{y=x}^{10}y \cdot\frac{ {7\choose y-x }{p^{y-2x}(1-p)^{4-y+2x}}}{{3\choose x}}$

Am I headed in the right direction? Any idea about how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is correct, but it might be tedious to continue the computations.

It is much easier to write $Y = Z_1 + \cdots + Z_{10}$ where each $Z_i$ is a $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ random variable. Then use linearity of expectation and note that $Z_4, \ldots, Z_{10}$ are independent of $X$, while $E[Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3 \mid X=x] = x$.